# Python buffer decode

Tags: python, buffer, decode, encode

I have a UDP package that is sent from a C++ program and I have to read it in Python. I managed to receive the UDP package but unfortunately it is encoded. 
The C++ data has the form

```
struct packet{
    double arg1
    double arg2
    double arg3
    double arg4
    int16_t arg5
};
```

The data I receive is in total 42 bytes long (which is the same length that is also sent). Maybe the the data is also slightly changed before it is sent, but I'm still trying to figure that out.
So my question is: Let's assume the structure of the sent data would be exactly as described above. How could I read it out from the buffer? (Btw. I'm using Python 2.7.9)

Thx already

Edit: I found something about the structure

```
void Send(const CrazyFliePacket& packet)
    {
        FMA::ByteBuffer p = 
            FMA::Encode((PACKET_TYPE)FMA_PACKET_TYPES::CRAZYFLIE) + 
            FMA::Encode((PACKET_VERSION)0) +
            FMA::Encode(_seq++) + 
            packet.Encode();

        _server->SendPacket(p.data(),p.size());
        printf("Packet sent with %i bytes size\n",p.size());
    }
```

Types are:

```
typedef unsigned short PACKET_TYPE;
typedef unsigned short PACKET_VERSION;
uint16_t _seq;
```

the sent and received data is now 40 bytes long.

Edit2: The correct solution is

```
print struct.unpack('<HHhddddh', data)
```

Comment: Encoded: how? This C++ code does not tell how the `packet` is encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) is what you are looking for. Anyhow you have to find out the serialized data format. It is not a C/C++ struct that is sent but (hopefilly) a well described serialized format which may be binaray. Important topics are little/big endianess, size of double, size of int and padding.

```
from struct import *
arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 = unpack('!ddddi', buffer)
```

standard sizes would require 36 bytes

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> a='\x00\x00\x00\x01'*9
>>> unpack('>ddddi', a)
(2.1219957915e-314, 2.1219957915e-314, 2.1219957915e-314, 2.1219957915e-314, 1)
>>> unpack('<ddddi', a)
(7.291122046717944e-304, 7.291122046717944e-304, 7.291122046717944e-304, 7.291122046717944e-304, 16777216)
>>> unpack('!ddddi', a)
(2.1219957915e-314, 2.1219957915e-314, 2.1219957915e-314, 2.1219957915e-314, 1)
>>>
```

---

EDIT: unpacking to variables, named tuple and class

**unpack directly to your variables**

```
from struct import unpack 
b = "\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x2a"

x, y = unpack('!ii', b)
print x
print y
```

**unpack to named tuple**

```
from struct import unpack 
from collections import namedtuple
b = "\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x2a"

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x, y')

p = Point._make(unpack("!ii", b))
print p.x
print p.y
```

remember: tuple attributes are read only

**unpack and initalize a class**

```
from struct import unpack 
b = "\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x2a"

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

p = Point(*unpack('!ii', b))
print p.x
print p.y
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I read somewhere in the code that it is binary. I'm however still trying to figure out how it is exactly composed. But I think what you wrote is finally what I need. What is the difference between the 3 unpacks?

Comment: little endian (intel) vs big endian (motorola, network byte order)

Comment: Ok.I think I found where the additional bytes come from, see edit in question.

Comment: I tried unpack but it doesnt work. I cant use from struct import* since that would give some error elsewhere. If I just use import struct. Is there no unpack function?

Comment: standard sizes would require 36 bytes of packed data. if your data length is only 34 bytes, the sender may be a 16-bit machine with an integer size of 2 bytes. in that case the format string contains a short `unpack('!ddddh', a)`. you should check type and version as well to avoid deserialzing unknown data. you should also check the sequence number for continuity to detect communication problems.

Comment: python basics :-). if you do `import struct`you must use `struct.unpack()`

Comment: That was a spelling error. So I added all the missing data types and specified the int. I'm a Matlab guy, that's why ;)

Comment: It worked with your second version. Thx very much. I'd offer you a beer, but you probably don't live around here ;).

Answer (score 2):

I too used struct unpacking (and had to search the character codes every time) until I learned to do the same using ctypes. I have no idea which one performs faster, but I do know which one I can translate without problems just looking at the C definition.

```
from ctypes import LittleEndianStructure, BigEndianStructure, c_int16, c_double, sizeof
#there are bit explicit types if you want to fix the size, like c_int8/16/32/64

class Packet(LittleEndianStructure): # replace by BigEndian as needed
    _fields_ = [
        ("arg1", c_double),
        ("arg1", c_double),
        ("arg3", c_double),
        ("arg4", c_double),
        ("arg5", c_int16)
        ]
    _pack_=1 # comment this or not depending on padding

mypacket = Packet.from_buffer_copy(payload)
```

It is for me much easier to read, and it has the advantage of providing me with an object that collects all the data and can be accessed by name

```
print(mypacket.arg1)
```